# query to ignore duplicate/null records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Below are the 3 tables which we need to join to get the data

```
 TableA         TableB               TableC
    AId          BId     Name      CId       DeclareDate  value
    1            1       abc       1         September      11
    2            2       def       1         October        12
    3            3       xyz       1         November       13
    4            4       pqr       1         December       14
    5            5       ghi       2         September      15
                                   3         October        16
                                   4         August         17
                                   5         October        18
                                   5         December       19
```

From TableC we have same fund with CId 1 is declaring in all the 4 months, in that case I need only the december row and if the fund is not declaring in december then I need to get the null valure for that C id.
So the output table should look like below.

Output Table

```
   AId    BId  name     DeclareDate   value
    1      1    abc     December      14
    2      2    def     null          null
    3      3    xyz     null          null
    4      4    pqr     null          null
    5      5    ghi     december      19
```

So finally if there are no declared dates in december then return null, if there are multiple declare dates then return only the december record.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your logic is not clear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if you consider funds with I'd 1 and 5 from tableC, they have declare dates in multiple months, in that case we need to get only fund that has declare date on December and ignore remaining, and if you consider other fund ids 2,3,4 they don't have declaredate on december, in that case we need to return null value instead of returning declaringdate

Comment: Why was December chosen for 1 and 5?  Is it because it is the latest month?

Comment: I tried this, select (column names from tables) from tableA A inner join tableB B on A.AId = B.BId inner join TableC C on A.AId = C.CId where C.declareDate between '01-DEC-16' and '31-DEC-16'; the above query returned me only two records 1 and 5                                                               AId    BId  name  CId  DeclareDate   value
    1      1    abc   1         December    14

Answer (score 2):

use left join into table C

```
  select a.*,b.*, c.DeclareDate, c.Value from TableA a
   inner join TableB b on  a.AI =b.BId
  left join 
  (select * from TableC where DeclareDate='December') c
   on b.BId = c.CId
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: This returns only December rows, we need to get non December rows also as null values

Comment: its same, (select * from TableC where DeclareDate='December') return two record december, then left join into tableA and tableB, the return null if not december rows. you are has been try it?

Comment: As shown in output table for an I'd if there are declare dates in multiple months then we need to get December record for that I'd , if a I'd is not present in December then we need to return null value for that I'd

Comment: @RMS -- I tested this against the sample data, and it does yield your desired results...  note the left join

Comment: @RMS -- if work can you change my answer to be a true answer? :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say DeclareDate is an actual date, and you only want the values from December, maybe something like this would work?

```
select
  a.AId, b.BId, b.Name,
  coalesce (c.CId, A.AId) as CId,
  c.DeclareDate, c.Value
from
  TableA a
  join TableB b on a.AId = b.BId
  left join TableC c on
    a.AId = c.CId and
    extract (month from c.DeclareDate) = 12
```

This assumes a whole lot -- notably that if you have multiple dates in December, they will all show up.  Also, it doesn't check the year...  is any old December adequate?

If you literally meant the text string "December" then you could change that second condition in the left join to `c.DeclareDate = 'December'`.

If you have some broader examples, maybe it will help pin down the exact logic.

-- EDIT --

Here is some sample code to build and test:

```
insert into tablea values (1);
insert into tablea values (2);
insert into tablea values (3);
insert into tablea values (4);
insert into tablea values (5);
insert into tableb values (1, 'abc');
insert into tableb values (2, 'def');
insert into tableb values (3, 'xyz');
insert into tableb values (4, 'pqr');
insert into tableb values (5, 'ghi');
insert into tablec values (1, 'September', 11);
insert into tablec values (1, 'October', 12);
insert into tablec values (1, 'November', 13);
insert into tablec values (1, 'December', 14);
insert into tablec values (2, 'September', 15);
insert into tablec values (3, 'October', 16);
insert into tablec values (4, 'August', 17);
insert into tablec values (5, 'October', 18);
insert into tablec values (5, 'December', 19);
```

And the solution:

```
select
  a.AId, b.BId, b.Name,
  coalesce (c.CId, A.AId) as CId,
  c.DeclareDate, c.Value
from
  TableA a
  join TableB b on a.AId = b.BId
  left join TableC c on
    a.AId = c.CId and
    c.DeclareDate = 'December';
```

Results:

```
AID BID NAME  CID   DECLAREDATE VALUE
1   1   abc   1     December    14
2   2   def   2     
3   3   xyz   3     
4   4   pqr   4     
5   5   ghi   5     December    19
```

Comment: This gets only December records. As shown in output table for an I'd if there are declare dates in multiple months then we need to get December record for that I'd , if a I'd is not present in December then we need to return null value for that I'd

Comment: I believe this does exactly that...  the "left join" guarantees the records even without matches come back.

Comment: I added some sample code to fiddle...  this definitely retains the non-december rows.

Comment: I just tested , looks good, I will implement tomorrow and let you know, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

select a.AID,b.DeclareDate,b.VAL from TABLEA a left outer join (select * from TABLEB where DeclareDate='December') b on a.AID=b.BID order by a.AID asc